# How to show Label Text from Datatable?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web

I am having a label which I am creating through code. I want to populate this label through a function which returns me a DataTable. This DataTable has 1 row and 1 column in the return.

This is my code:

```
Label1.??? = Repository.Instance.ReturnScore(ddlPlayer1.ToString(), ddlPlayer2.ToString());
```

ReturnScore is giving me the value as DataTable. How should I get the value in it?

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Label1.Text =  Repository.Instance.ReturnScore(ddlPlayer1.ToString(), ddlPlayer2.ToString()).Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
DataTable table = Repository.Instance.ReturnScore(ddlPlayer1.ToString(), ddlPlayer2.ToString());
object value = table.Rows[0][0];
Label1.Text = value == DBNull.Value ? "" : value.ToString() ;
```

This returns the first value of the first row.

Comment: it should be `table.Rows[0][0].ToString()` I think.

Comment: @StackOverflowException, you're right, it needs to be converted to a string.  It also needs to have a DBNull check in there.

Answer (score 0):

DataTable has a Rows property, and each Row returned by Rows has an indexer which yields the values contained in the columns for that row. Since you have said there will be just one row and one column, you can do this:

```
DataTable table = Repository.Instance.ReturnScore(ddlPlayer1.ToString(), ddlPlayer2.ToString());
DataRow row = table.Rows[0];
Label1.Text = row[0];
```

or more concisely:

```
Label1.Text = Repository.Instance.ReturnScore(ddlPlayer1.ToString(), ddlPlayer2.ToString())[0][0];
```

Comment: Rows has "an array property" is not fully accurate.  It's called an **indexer**.

Answer (score -1):

I don't remember the exact code but I think it should be something like:

```
dt.Rows[index]["columName"]
```